# Structure of complex file formats

Tags: file-structure

Suppose I want design and implement a a large and complex file format, like pdf or docx; how do I have to structure it? How can they contain so many different data types like images, macros or graphics?

Edit: for structures I mean the ways for storing different data types, I don't think that a plain binary file is so viable. 
The file format that I want to design is like a Word page with various multimedia contents. 
It's an word processor application for mobile platforms which needs a custom file format for its particular structure, I know that is a time consuming task but what I need is a extensible base structure which I can expand in future

Comment: You can model it however you wish.  Just think about where your priorities lie:  size?  readability?  ease of being read by your program?

Comment: What kind of application do you have in mind? Please **edit your question** again to tell that

Comment: But why do you need your format? Why not use existing things: OpenDocument, or existing text formatters (like LaTeX or Lout)?

Comment: But you still don't explain why do you want that and for what exact kind of application. What is the overall problem you want to achieve? Is your future application free software? Do you have several years of full-time work ahead of you?

Comment: For high-level strategies: I'd recommend you look at [multipart Email messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages) for a well-known example of embedding multiple files/formats/attachments into a single file. The other common strategy is simply using a ZIP archive to bundle a bunch of files, this is used by .docx, .jar. .epub and many other formats. This is very flexible since the archive can be treated like a folder/directory, the compression is an additional benefit.

Comment: There's no such thing as a plain binary file.

Comment: To understand how well-known, existing formats are structured, you can study their specifications; you can find a lot of information on http://www.fileformat.info/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Suppose I want design and implement a a large and complex file format, like pdf or docx

If you are alone, I would try hard to **avoid such a large specification effort**. In particular, consider instead:

- using *existing* **textual formats** such as [JSON](http://json.org/), [YAML](http://yaml.org/) or maybe [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) or [S-Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression); then you still need to specify how you would use these, e.g. define names of attributes or of tags (and specify their roles and rules for using them) .
- using *existing* **database engines**, perhaps [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) or genuine RDBMS servers like [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) (or non-relational database servers à la MongoDB). BTW, it is often worthwhile to have textual structured data (e.g. JSON) inside databases; of course you still need to specify a database schema and the set of requests used on it. In some cases key-value indexed files (à la [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) or [TokyoCabinet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Cabinet_and_Kyoto_Cabinet)) could be enough.
- using and extending *existing* **embeddable interpreters** (à la [Lua](http://lua.org/) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile)) and having your file becoming a script for that interpreter
- defining some (preferably textual) [domain specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) (which is quite close to extend some interpreter), inspired by existing ones.

> How can they contain so many different data types like images, macros or graphics?

These are only sequences of bytes having some metadata (perhaps some [content type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type)).

If you really want to design a large and complex file format, think about portability (between machine architectures : word size, endianness) and extensibility first.
Specify your format on paper (e.g. using some EBNF notation) and have it reviewed by others. Write a sample implementation library to parse and
generate that format (incrementally, while you are specifying it).

**Make your specification publicly available** to enable feedback from outside. Make your sample implementation library free software or open source.

**Data often outlive software**, so work hard to get a reasonable format right.

If you still do define your format, be aware that it could take you *years* of work to get it right.

Study *existing* file formats before inventing your own. Notice that a  file format is successful only when *several* applications are using it, so there is an important social issue (convincing others to use your format), hence you should try to specify it with some other people.

> Edit: for structures I mean the ways for storing different data types, I don't think that a plain binary file is so viable

Read also about [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

> The file format that I want to design is like a Word page with various multimedia contents

Study existing formats, e.g. [OpenDocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument). If possible, adapt it. Otherwise, budget a dozen years of full time effort. Try to find several senior engineers to work with you.

<sup>(very probably your format and your software would be *ignored*, consider that possibility seriously)</sup>

Remember that on current computers, I/O (network or disk, even SSD) is [*much slower*](http://norvig.com/21-days.html#answers) than CPU (more than a thousand times slower), so the parsing and writing CPU time of textual formats is generally much less than I/O time. In other words, the network or the disk or SSD is always the bottleneck. And textual formats (à la JSON, etc...) are much easier to debug.

> It's an word processor application for mobile platforms which needs a custom file format for its particular structure,

I would still recommend using some *existing* format, or at least a *strict subset* (and well specified one) of some existing format. Why can't you use EPUB, some subset of OpenDocument, or a subset of HTML? Look also into the HTML-like formats used by GTK and by Qt, at least for inspiration (and perhaps by using such a library).

The advantage of such an approach is that you won't need to code a lot of converters (since you would be able to reuse some of the existing ones).

PS. If you just want to produce a nice looking document (e.g. in PDF) from some code, consider instead generating some textual file to feed it to some [typesetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typesetting) system like [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) or [Lout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lout_(software)), or find then use a library to emit PDF files.

Comment: You forgot filesystem-like structures such as zip archives used to store [epub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB) books.

Comment: I've also found The Art of Unix Programming to have [useful advice on designing textual file formats](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch05s02.html). It has a good overview of various styles. However, textual formats are ill suited for a collection of resources that are modified independently because you have to write the whole document in one pass. Binary formats can jump to and patch relevant sections independently.

Comment: zip archives are also used to store the XML and resources for for MS Office docx, xlsx, etc file formats.